# Get Everything before and after a character/pattern in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column from which i want to extract everything before and after a string. I have the following entry:

`[{"model": "test.question", "pk": 123456789, "fields": {"status": "graded"}}]`
`[{"model": "test.question", "pk": 123456789, "fields": {"status": "answered"}}]`

I want to extract the substring after **"status": {"** and before **}}]**

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `LIKE` keyword will let you use `%` as a wildcard.  The rest is just straight text matching.  So, you should be able to use something like

`WHERE columnName LIKE 'status":{"%}}]`

(replace `columnName` with your column, of course).

---

However, if you have structured data in a table, you might want to reconsider your options.  MySQL has a JSON data type (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) which may let you query more directly and correctly - for example, the approach I've described above will break if somehow a status exists that includes the string `}}]`.

---

If you want the substring itself, MySQL has a `substring` function, detailed at MySQL has a `SUBSTRING` function, detailed at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring , which you would use in your `SELECT` clause, probably using `LOCATE` to get the index to use in the substring.  Without seeing your current SQL, it's tough to describe how that would have to be put together.

Comment: I want the substring "graded" and "answered" which is between **"status": {"** and **}}]**

Comment: I've edited with a bit more description of how you'd have to modify your SELECT clause in order to get just that.